# How do I calculate a cumulative value without using python or php?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with:

- location_id (`location`) - ranges from 0-90,000
- time (`time_period`) - ranges from 1-15 for each location
- temperature (`temp`) - A unique value for each location x time_period.

Example data:

```
location time_period temp
91         1          -4
91         2          3
91         3          12
.......................
.......................
91         15         20
```

I'd like to create a new field called `cum_temp` and add the cumulative value for each cell till that current time_period. My current thought is to do duplicate the table and run:

```
update site_a 
   set cum_temp = (select sum(temp) 
                     from site_a_copy 
                    where site_a_copy.location = site_a.location 
                      and site_a_copy.time_period <= site_a.time_period);
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this or can you suggest something better?

Comment: Just curious, but what does the sum of the temperatures mean?  Is it only to calculate the average?  I can't think of a good reason, but I am sure I am just being close-minded.

Comment: It's the total temperature any particular site has experience up to a given time. So if I sum up all the temperature values from time 1 through 10, at time 10, that particular location site has experienced a cumulative temperature equal to that sum. I use it in the context of snow melt and plant growth.

I am not using it to calculate an average.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't need a separate table, unless you don't want to store the cumulative temperature in one of them.

Running a query periodically or manually will work (though do it from a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)), or you can try to use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) to do it automatically:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum_temp
  BEFORE INSERT ON site
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.cum_temp = NEW.temp + (
        SELECT SUM(temp) FROM site 
          WHERE site.location_id = NEW.location_id
            AND site.`time` < NEW.`time`
      );
```

However, triggers for this application are fraught with peril. For one, the above won't update any rows that are temporally after the new row. As long as you only append new records, this isn't a serious problem. Getting a trigger to update later rows is basically impossible, as row level locks prevent you from issuing UPDATEs to the same table within INSERT and UPDATE triggers. Storing the cumulative temperature in another table would get around this.

Second, when inserting multiple values with a single INSERT statement, the new rows must be in temporal order in the statement, else the cumulative temperature will be set improperly. Rows that are earlier in time but later in the INSERT won't be taken into account when calculating the cumulative temperature for rows later in time but earlier in the INSERT. This is a consequence to the first issue.

You could also use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW site_a AS
    SELECT *, SUM(temp) AS cum_temp
      FROM site AS s
      JOIN site AS t 
        ON s.location_id=t.location_id AND s.time_period >= t.time_period
;
```

See also "[UPDATE TABLE WITH SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182072/update-table-with-sum/)"